# How to read Output of Console Command in Yii?

Tags: yii, php, yii-events, yiic

I am trying to build some cron jobs to do backup some critical data on my Yii WebApplication
I have built the the CConsoleCommand Class that needs to run. It runs fine and the command is executed

However my job requires the application to parse the output of the command being run and act accordingly.

Is there any way to do this from inside Yii framework?? Or is there in any alternative in php-CLi that will let me easily integrate my current class in Yii ??

Comment: I do know you can read the $exitCode of run command for success or failure of an command. But I am need to parse an successful output to take further action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this extension, may be helpful
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tconsolerunner